# CSS: Div to float down if page is scrolled

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a fixed div, so that even if i scroll down the page, the div remains in the center of the page. But I'm having a problem that some part of the div remains hidden even if scroll down the page. Please see this [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yDPcN/) to see the code and the problem.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="main">Normal div </div>
    <div class="box">This should be in the slide down if page is scrolled down.</div>   
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrap{
    border: 1px solid green;
    width:500px;
    overflow:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.main{
    border:1px solid blue;
     width:400px;
    float:right;
}

.box{
    border:1px solid red;
    width:85px;
    top:200px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When an element is absolutely positioned or fixed, you can use the `top` and `bottom` CSS properties to force the element to fill exactly the screen's height:

```
.box{
border:1px solid red;
position: fixed;
width:85px;
bottom:0px;
top:0px;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto
}
```

Or to be vertically centered on the screen:

```
.box{
border: 1px solid red;
position: fixed;
width:85px;
bottom: 20%;
top: 20%;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto
}
```

The rule `overflow-y: auto` ensures that a vertical scrollbar will appear if needed, while the rule `overflow-x: hidden;` is there to prevent a horizontal scroolbar from showing up.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to go through the pain of javascript, just set `top`, `height` and `overflow` attributes for `.box`. Your problem is that you haven't set `height` and `overflow`. For example:

```
.box{
    border:1px solid red;
    width:85px;
    top:200px;
    position: fixed;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll; /* or hidden */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following javascript to center you div on a screen

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getwidth() {       
        if (typeof (window.innerWidth) == 'number')
            return window.innerWidth;
        else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth) //IE 6+
            return document.documentElement.clientWidth;        
        return 0;
    };

    function getheight() {      
        if (typeof (window.innerHeight) == 'number')
            return window.innerHeight;
        else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) //IE 6+
            return document.documentElement.clientHeight;       
        return 0;
    };

    function getscroll() {      
        if (self.pageYOffset)       
            return self.pageYOffset;
        else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop)
            return document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        else if (document.body)     
            return document.body.scrollTop;     
        return 0;
    };

    function show(mydivW, mydivH) {
        var w = getwidth() / 2 - mydivW / 2;
        var h = getheight() / 2 - mydivH / 2 + getscroll();
        var box = document.getElementById('mydiv');
        box.style.top = h + 'px';
        box.style.left = w + 'px';
        box.style.display = 'block';
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the behaviour of fixed position, if you don't know the height of the fixed `<div>` you cannot center it vertically with only CSS.
However you can use some JavaScript tricks to adapt the sidebar with the screen resolution like [here](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/).